# Swift, Xib variables pass data to variable

Tags: ios, swift, xib, nib

I cant seem to make this work the way I want.

I have created a xib file from which I pick a table cell. I want to add some variables that I modify before returning the cell to the TableView.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:MakeMeTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("t5Cell") as! MakeMeTableViewCell
        cell.questionNumberLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)."
        cell.customVariable = "\(indexPath.row + 1)."
        return cell
    }
```

Swift for xib

```
import UIKit

class Take5TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var questionNumberLabel: UILabel!

    var customVariable = ""

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        println("label: \(questionNumberLabel.text)")
        println("variable: \(customVariable)")
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }



}
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
label: Optional("1.")
variable: 
label: Optional("1.")
variable: 
label: Optional("1.")
variable: 
label: Optional("1.")
variable: 
label: Optional("1.")
variable:
```

The output I was hoping for would be label: 1..2..3, variable: 1..2..3

Comment: what are you planning on using the variable for?

Comment: @sophiefader I want to use it in the table cell in a programmable label .

Comment: are you sure awakeFromNib isn't called before (!) you set the values?

Comment: Cells are reused, so  you're probably going to want to change your label in cellForRowAtIndexPath not in the cell's awake method, and print there as well to check the value.

Comment: in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method : 

      cell.questionlabel.text = "\(indexPath.text)"
      println("\(cell.questionlabel.text)") 

See if that gives the results you're expecting